# CODE FOR THE BELOW QUESTION (ALARM MANAGER)

Tags: android

Write code for the following and explain.
To wake up the device to fire the alarm at approximately 2:00 p.m and repeat once a day at the same time.
To wake up the device to fire the alarm at precisely 8:30 a.m., and every 20 minutes thereafter.
Start an alarm when device restarts.

Comment: Stack Overflow is good to answer questions you have, you should show what you have, and what you're having issues with. We don't do your homework.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Tell me what you have done, what you have found, what you did. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should read [Android's training samples](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#java) They answer both of these questions word for word. I'll provide one of the samples here but you should look up the second yourself so you can actually learn what's going on.

```
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```